# Is there a way I'm supposed to configure react-native-markdown-renderer in an expo application?

Tags: react-native, expo, markdown

I want to display markdown content in an expo RN application.

`npx expo install react-native-markdown-renderer -- --legacy-peer-deps`

I've installed react-native-markdown-renderer but when I import Markdown from the installed package and I try using it, my content is not displayed at all.

`import Markdown from 'react-native-markdown-renderer`

Could there be something that I'm supposed

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { COLOR } from '../../../constants/contants';
import Header from '../../NewsDetails/helperComponents/Header';
import Markdown from 'react-native-markdown-renderer';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Privacy = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch_data = async () => {

        const response = await fetch(url)
        const results = await response.json()

        setContent(results?.data.attributes?.body);
      
    }

    fetch_data();
  }, [content]);



  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Header title='Privacy Policy' />
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View>
            <Markdown>{content}</Markdown>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Privacy;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: COLOR.WHITE
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'justify',
    fontFamily: 'RalewayMedium'
  },
  scroll: {
    padding: 10
  }
})
```

I'm getting the error below

```
 ERROR  [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module punycode from /home/enock/Desktop/Ablestate/needed/Insightify/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/index.js: punycode could not be found within the project or in these directories:
```